# Change Run/Debug Cloud Service service configuration on build

Tags: visual-studio, azure-cloud-services

When right-clicking a Cloud Services project in Visual Studio and selecting Properties, you get the following screen:

[image]

I'm trying to change the highlighted value at build time, but it doesn't seem to be kept in the .ccproj project file... so where are these settings persisted? Are they programatically modifiable?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to change the highlighted value at build time, but it doesn't seem to be kept in the .ccproj project file... so where are these settings persisted?

As I known, you could find the setting under `LocalProfile` section from your `AzureCloudService.ccproj.user` file as follows:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ActivePublishProfile>brucecloudserviceProduction</ActivePublishProfile>
    <LocalProfile>Cloud</LocalProfile>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I tried to leverage [FileUpdate](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks/blob/master/Documentation/TaskDocs.md#FileUpdate) MSBuild task from [MSBuild Community Tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks) for changing `LocalProfile` setting during build time. Since you changed the setting after your project is loaded, if you build your project via Visual Studio, the changes would no be applied to your project. Based on my test, you could build your Azure project from command line and specify the `TargetProfile` property of the MSBuild command as follows:

`MSBuild MyCloudService.ccproj /p:TargetProfile=Cloud`

Assuming your target service configuration file looks like this: `ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg`. For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-command-line-build).

Comment: Hmm, even when that file is edited with MSBuild, it's only reloaded into Visual Studio after unloading and reloading the project. Any way to get around that requirement?

Comment: According to your description, I did some trials, you could see my update.